# async.js issues in node js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have 2 nested async.each. They look like:

```
 async.each(result, function(row, callbackrow) {
   tot = 0;
   console.log('UID:', row.uid);

   async.each(row.vbs, function(vb, callback){
     checkInteractions(row.uid, vb.vbNID, function(data){
       console.log(data);
       callback();
     });
   }, function(err){ console.log('done 1'); });

   callbackrow();  
}, function(err){ console.log("done all"); });
```

My problem is, the `checkinteraction` async call causes problems. Without it, console logs are called from second each for each one of the first async each. With it, I get the done all message, and after the nested (second) async each executes its code. I need it to be like a synchronus call of a for inside a for. For each element of first for, the second one to be executed before stepping to next index in the first for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `callbackrow` should be passed as final callback of the inner loop, so that the outer loop knows when to step to the next iteration, like so:

```
async.each(result, function(row, callbackrow) {
  tot = 0;
  console.log('UID:', row.uid);

  async.each(row.vbs, function(vb, callback){
    checkInteractions(row.uid, vb.vbNID, function(data){
      console.log(data);
      callback();
    });
  }, function(err){ 
    console.log('done 1'); 
    callbackrow();
  });

}, function(err){ console.log("done all"); });
```

Comment: tryed it too. i get the final callbacks console logs in order. that data log from async check it's still executed after the outer loop call its final log callback.